# How to use notifyDataSetChanged in SwipeToFresh

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a project implemented using volley, it works fine the listView gets its data from mysql. However, when data is updated in the database, the same is not reflected in the android app despite using notifydatasetchanged(). I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426) and tried implementing with no success. Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends  ActionBarActivity  {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView listView;
private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private String URL_FEED = "http://10.0.2.2/project/items.php";

SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    GetDataTask();

swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);

swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
{ @Override public void onRefresh() { 
    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true); 
    Log.d("Swipe", "Refreshing content"); 
    ( new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        @Override public void run() { 
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false); 

                // notify data changes to list adapater
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } }, 8000); } });

    swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
            android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
}

public void GetDataTask(){

    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
    if (entry != null) {
        // fetch the data from cache
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                        if (response != null) {
                            parseJsonFeed(response);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you need to re fetch the data from the web service not just with the setDatachange will refresh your list.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the GetDataTask function within setOnRefreshListener.
You need to call if after notifying listAdapter about dataset changes.

This works for me
        SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener onRefreshListener = new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){

```
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            Log.d("Swipe", "Refreshing content");

            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            GetDataTask();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        } };
```